# What will happen if a context switch is triggered in a serial DispatchQueue?

Tags: swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, swift-playground

In principle, a serial `DispatchQueue` will execute the submitted tasks one after another. But what if a context switch is triggered in one task (say, calling `sleep`)? Does the queue execute the next task right away, or wait for the current task to finish?

For this code:

```
q.async {
    print("IN 1")
    var i = 1
    while i < 10 {
     Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.1)
     i += 1
    }
    print("OUT of 1")
}

q.async {
    print("IN 2")
}
```

Is the result:

```
// IN 1 -> OUT of 1 -> IN 2 ?
// or IN 1 -> IN 2 -> OUT of 1 ?
```

I tried running the code in playground, but it seems `sleep` (and `Thread.sleep`) doesn't work within Playground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In principle, a serial DispatchQueue will execute the submitted tasks one after another. But what if a context switch is triggered in one task (say, calling sleep)? Does the queue execute the next task right away, or wait for the current task to finish?

A serial queue is not "serial" just because its tasks are submitted serially (indeed, most tasks usually are, even on parallel queues), but because the tasks are guaranteed to be completed one by one, in the order they were submitted.

`Thread.sleep` works fine in a play ground, but your playground is terminating its execution early. The Playground's execution terminates when control flow reaches the end of the page. So asynchronous tasks like this will only finish if they happen to execute before the control flow reaches the end of the page, which is quite unlikely.

To keep the playground executing indefinitely (until manual termination), use:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for the tip on PlaygroundSupport!

Answer (score 5):

A serial queue does not begin executing the next block until the previous one finishes. Context switching does not affect this. If you call `sleep` in a block submitted to a serial queue, that will block the queue until the sleep finishes and your block can resume executing. So your result will be `IN 1 -> OUT of 1 -> IN 2`.

Note that in general you don't want to do blocking things (like `sleep`) in a block submitted to a queue, because that will block the whole thread, making it unavailable for libdispatch to use for other work. libdispatch will spin up new threads as needed to continue working, but there's a limit to how many new threads it will spawn.